# How to remove [Thr-1] from Rails logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, logging

My logs are prepended with `[Thr-1]` or `[Thr-2]` and I can't figure out how to disable this behavior. I assume that they are the thread names, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

By default the log format is set to `SeverityID, [DateTime #pid] SeverityLabel -- ProgName: message`

Ref: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.4/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-Format

You can confirm or change the log format in `config/environments/<environment>.rb` file under `config.log_formatter` option.
Ex: `config/environments/production.rb` for production environment.

I guess ProgName in your case is having thread name, you can debug and update this behavior by overriding the log_format.

Try,

```
logger.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
    # Debug statements here
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I just found out that this was being added by Phusion Passenger when running in threaded mode. Not sure how to disable it yet.